# WPF check if control is dragged

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

Is there a way to check, if the user is currently dragging a control in WPF? Events to handle start-drag and drop don't do the trick in my current application. Of course, a simple workaround could be implemented by just setting a bool-flag, which is set during start-drag, so a drag-n-drop can be seen as active.

Unfortunately, that solution is not very robust, since you have to manually reset that flag on drop - and have to think of all the possibilities, which could cause a drop-event to never occur (user presses ESC, not dropped into an allowDrop-control, ...).

Answer (score 2):

I have a hacky sort of solution that I've come up with after spending lots of time trying to understand drag and drop in WPF.

The WPF [`InputManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.inputmanager) which is "responsible for coordinating all of the input systems in WPF", does technically have a property that says whether or not a drag and drop operation is currently in progress.

```
/// <summary>
///     The InDragDrop property represents whether we are currently inside
///     a OLE DragDrop operation.
/// </summary>
internal bool InDragDrop
```

The above is from the official .NET Framework source code. Specifically [`InputManager.cs`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/system/windows/Input/InputManager.cs,ab8bc89434da939a).

The problem is that, for some reason, it's declared as an `internal` property, so we can't access it... or at least we're not supposed to. `internal` and `private` members can still be accessed using [refection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection). So `InputManager.InDragDrop` can technically be read by doing the following:

VB.NET

```
GetType(InputManager).GetProperty("InDragDrop", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(InputManager.Current)
```

C#:

```
typeof(InputManager).GetProperty("InDragDrop", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(InputManager.Current);
```

I have used this and it does work, but its not an officially supported feature of WPF so use at your own risk. There's technically a chance that Microsoft could change the way `InputManager` works in the future and remove or rename this property, thought personally I doubt it.